# how to add eventListener click on multiple div with different custom data-key attribute

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, html5-audio

So i have multiple divs with different `data-key` attributes as

```
<div data-key="65" class="key">
  <kbd>A</kbd>
  <span class="sound">clap</span>
</div>
```

and i have multiple audio with `data-key` as attribute

```
<audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
```

now in `<script>` section using vanilla JS, I want to play sound with `data-key` same as div is being clicked on.
For example, if I click on div with `data-key="65"` it should play audio with `data-key="65"`.

I have a `keyDown` eventListener but i also want to implement with click on it.

I tried

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

but was not able to pickup anything that leads to div's attributes.

Comment: attach the 'keydown' event that returns a key code.

Comment: `e.target.getAttribute('data-key')`.

Comment: Or even `e.target.dataset.key`

Comment: I already have attached 'keydown' event for keyCode, i just want the function to also perform when clicked on it's div block

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all div has `data-key` attribute and `.key` using [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop through them.
2. In loop add `click` event handler using [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
3. In event handler function, get value of `data-key` using [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.
4. Select audio tag that has specific `data-key` value using attribute equal selector.
5. Play audio by [`.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play)

```
document.querySelectorAll(".key").forEach(function(ele){
  ele.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var dataKey = this.dataset.key;
    document.querySelector("audio[data-key='"+dataKey +"']").play();
  });
})
```

Comment: Clear and concise answer with reference links explaining each line. +1

Comment: It's a CSS selector by attribute. `+` is basic string concatenation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Concatenating_strings

Comment: Thanks for answering, I didn't quite got the part with `audio[data-id='"+this.dataset.key+"']` edit - Specifically the + syntax

Comment: @veksen The [`Document.querySelector()` use CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Parameters). Also i used basic string concatenation instead of [string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to simplify the code and better understanding.

Comment: @JayC The `audio[data-key='1']` is selector that select `audio` tag has `data-key` attribute with value `1`. But i used variable `dataKey` instead of `1` string in selector. Note that `+` is [string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Concatenating_strings)

Answer (score 1):

One method is to attach event listeners to each key. The other way is to attach a listener to a parent node (preferably not `document`) and use event propagation to catch the events as they bubble up the DOM. The clicked element will be in the event target property.

Here I've wrapped the keys in a key-group that contains the listener.

```js
const group = document.querySelector('.key-group');
document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Deconstruct the target property and grab
  // the element's dataset, parentNode, and tagName
  const { dataset, parentNode, tagName } = e.target;

  // Depending on where you click you'll either need to test for
  // kbd or span elements...
  if (tagName === 'KBD' || tagName === 'SPAN') {

    // ...and log the key value of the parent dataset
    console.log(tagName, parentNode.dataset.key);
  }

  // Otherwise, if it's the div element
  if (tagName === 'DIV') {

    // ...log the key value from its dataset
    console.log(tagName, dataset.key);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="key-group">
  <div data-key="65" class="key">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
  </div>
  <div data-key="43" class="key">
    <kbd>F</kbd>
    <span class="sound">boom</span>
  </div>
</div>
```